# Question mark on raw folder

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a sound through the Soundplay class. I've used it many times, but this time it's not working.

There is a question mark on the res>raw folder which I created and put the .wav file in. Anyone know what that means?

Comment: do you use SVN? Question mark would mean that something new has been added, and has not yet been committed.

Comment: Where do you see that question mark? In Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

A question mark is nothing to worry about. It's used by Git and SVN to show that a file/folder is new and hasn't been added to version control

Answer (score 0):

You don't' worry about that i think you installed mercurial repository in your eclipse. To show that a file/folder is new and hasn't been added to version control.