# what is mean when the question mark appears on the database in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I create a database in Android and the database worked, then after a month when I opened the app again it appears problem. 
the problem is appear the question mark on the database.
what is mean when the question mark appears on the database?
like on the image.

[image]

Comment: It indicates that it is un-identified file format which means android studio doesn't have an editor to open the file. ignore it. it doesn't any sense.

Comment: @Lama Check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16953447/7424946